# Control periodic maintenance of services in a docker swarm

Tags: docker-swarm

A simplified version of my current setup is as follows:

- 3 virtual machines: VM1, VM2, VM3
- Each of them runs a `docker-compose` stack that includes a tomcat app and a DB.

The DB is recreated nightly from raw data (running a docker container that contains an indexing app).

This is achieved with crontab jobs, that are scheduled so that only 1 VM is in maintenance at any given time.

Now, this is going to scale up to several more VMs and possibly multiple replicas of this stack per VM. I am looking into docker swarm stacks to simplify the deployment and management.

The specific question is:

Once the deployment is managed via swarm, especially if the service is replicated into more than 1 instance per VM, how can I manage the nightly DB recreation, so that:

- all DBs are recreated
- I can control how many service instances, out of my cluster, are in maintenance mode at any given time?

I guess I could reformulate the question as: how to control maintenance at service level (vs node level)?

I do know that swarm nodes can be drained independently and be put in maintenance mode. The problem is that each node can contain a number of replicas of a service, and each of these replicas needs its own maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no maintenance mode for a Swarm Service.

You can't yet have tasks running in a Swarm Service and control enable/disable for each of them from the Routing Mesh and VIP load balancer.

You could get creative in various ways to control if the DB is listening on the port and how it updates the data (entrypoint script maybe), but that answer would require knowing a lot more about the system requirements, data flow, what needs to connect for DB update vs. client access, and if you're using volume drivers for DB data, etc. So that would be a different Q&A :)